# How to disable the button if the input has no arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following in my HTML thing, The input value will be populated by the user selection and store the values in the format of array( `45[45, 6, 33], 67[67,2,5] and so on..` ). Basically the value would be like the following:

```
<input id="question_string" type="hidden" value="{}">
<input class="submit_updates" name="commit" type="submit" value="Process">
```

Now i need to disable the submit button or alert some messages like 'Select all values' if the input has no arrays in the `{}`.

Updated:

```
var question_hash_element = document.getElementById('question_string');
var question_hash = JSON.parse(question_hash_element.value);

   var myArray = new Array();
      myArray[0] = window.batch_question_id;
      myArray[1] = window.answer_id || window.answer_text || window.batch_answer_checkbox
      myArray[2] = window.build_id
```

This bit of above code store the values into the `{}`. I just want to disable and let the user to select all the fields to process the form. If the values are `{}`, the button should disabled. and any of the values inside and it should be enabled.

I have tried like the following:

```
 $('.submit_updates').click(function () {
    if ($('#question_string') == {}) {
      return false;
      alert("Select all the Values");
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
```

It's not working..

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You currently are comparing `$('#question_string')` with an empty object literal, they never will be identical. What you want to compare is the [input value](http://api.jquery.com/val/) with the *string*  `"{}"`.

Comment: You may want to use [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) in your input, e.g., [[45, 6, 33], [67, 2, 5]].

Comment: This almost feels like you should use the jQuery data() functionality on those elements (without knowing much more about your solution of course)

Comment: @emallove its a valid JSON input only...

Comment: Show how your populate the #question_string input, that might allow us to assist you with a better/more fully vetted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning false before alerting the message.

Try this:

```
$('.submit_updates').on("click", function () {
  if ($('#question_string').val() == "{}") { //Adjusted condition
    //Alert message
    alert("Select all the Values");

    //Disable the submit button
    $(".submit_updates").prop("disabled", true);
    return false;
  } else {
  return true; //Not really needed
 }
});
```

It is nicer to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `click` and `attr`, as @adeneo suggests.

Comment: use .prop() for disabled not .attr() otherwise as of 1.9+ you will encounter issues – Mark Schultheiss

Comment: the values passed to the {}.. but its not submitted.. any guess?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.submit_updates').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ( $.trim($('#question_string').val())=='{}' ) {
       alert('no question !');
   }else{
       this.form.submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a flash message if its disabled button clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by "flash message" ?

Comment: @adeneo It's just alerting single time and when the values stored into the hashes... it doesn't enable. i guess

Comment: @Sri - edited again, that will give an alert without disabling the button, and submit the form if the value is something other than '{}' ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
     $('.submit_updates').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#question_string').val() == "{}") {
              $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled'); 
              alert("Select all the Values");
        } else {
        }
      });
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vT5wz/2/)***

Comment: use .prop() for disabled not `.attr()` otherwise as of 1.9+ you will encounter issues

Comment: @Mark thansk for ur suggesion. :-)